# How to find the average of a variable that has multiple subscripts?

Tags: stata

Let's say I have a variable X_ijt where i, j, and t are finite.

I want to find the average of every single possible combination of i, j and t.

So if i={1}, j={1,2}, and t={1,2,3} I would need 6 different means.

How can I do this?

Comment: `by i j t, sort: egen Xbar = mean(X)` will create a new variable `Xbar` containing the mean of `X` for those observations with the same values of `i`, `j`, and `t` as the given observation. If that's not what you need, you need to do a much better job of explaining what you want, starting with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm in agreement with others that this is unclear. Please give a concrete example of your data structure with an indication of what the answers would be. No example data, no attempt at code => falls short of standard MCVE question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve explains.

Comment: @William Lisowski thank you very much this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Nick Cox sorry it was my first or second time posting. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure where you would want to store this mean, but if I read your question literally:

```
foreach i of numlist 1{
    foreach j of numlist 1 2{
        foreach t of numlist 1 2 3{
            sum x if(i==`i' & j==`j' & t==`t'), meanonly
        }
    }
}
```

If `i`, `j`, and/or `t` have multiple values and you don't want to punch them all in manually to `numlists`, you can `levelsof`:

```
qui levelsof i, local(iLevels)
qui levelsof j, local(jLevels)
qui levelsof t, local(tLevels)

foreach i of local iLevels{
    foreach j of local jLevels{
        foreach t of local tLevels{
            sum x if(i==`i' & j==`j' & t==`t'), meanonly
        }
    }
}
```